# iOS XMPPFramework - How to get nickname of MUC message?

Tags: ios, xmppframework, multiuserchat

When I have joined a MUC room with XMPPFramwork I receive new messages via the delegate method:

```
func xmppRoom(sender: XMPPRoom!, didReceiveMessage message: XMPPMessage!, fromOccupant occupantJID: XMPPJID!) {

}
```

How can I get the **nickname** of the user who send the message?

I tried `message.from().user` but this did not print the nickname.

I now use `message.fromStr())!.lastPathComponent!` but this feels very wrong.

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try following,

Message.from().resource

Answer (score -1):

I know this is too late but, this answer may help others so I am posting answer

```
// this statement gives sender's nick name
message.attributeForName("from").stringValue
```

hope this helps.